# Created a regex to capture the email address out of each line of text in the txt file. What would be a more universal way of writing this?

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the email addresses out of each line of text out of a txt file on regex101.com.

Capturing everything after the "@" symbol was easy enough, but I ran into trouble because some of the emails contain "." which is a special character in regex. I managed to capture the right stuff, but the expression looks very clunky and I was wondering what a more efficient way of writing would be.

Expression:

```
(\w*\d*\.?\w*\d*\.?\d*\w*@\w*\.(?:com|miami))$
```

Working txt file:

```
Jazmine Holcomb 3212 Adams Avenue Washington MD eluir.azevedo.7o@lucidmode.com
Sofie Hagan 4241 Jerry Dove Drive Erie PA zfraction00t@jfaccupuncture.com
Cairo Tyson 3768 Clifford Street San_Jose CA varifi.amin@disabilitylawyersatlanta.com
Tasmin Kearney 2956 Adams Drive El_Campo CA 1paul.clinssonq@aprilmovo.com
Aydin Moran 3727 Sarah Drive Lake_Charles LA 3egdol@blogspot.miami
Samirah Pollard 946 Douglas Dairy Road Prosperity SC rzekohahaha@gmailup.com
Jaskaran Wheeler 1521 Richards Avenue Torrance CA ardit.ditty@netfacc.com
Gerrard Browning 4690 Felosa Drive Los_Angeles CA cgbeshar@lotomoneymaker.com
Haleema Craft 73 Pinchalone Street Norfolk VA 0kjhdsxz123e@summitgg.com
Brett Neal 4079 Johnson Street Garner NC fali_gx2000w@plussmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex instead:

```sh
\w[\w-]*(?:\.\w[\w-]*)*@\w+\.(?:com|miami)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GVxuKa/1)

Comment: Yes that regex is a bit more complex :)

Answer (score 2):

`\w[\w.]+\w@\w[\w.]*\.(com|miami)$` should match everything as well, as `\w` matches both digits and letters.

Anyway, if email contained characters different from *letters*, *digits* and *underscore* `_` though, neither mine nor your regex will match.

Comment: Note that your patterns might miss a leading part of the email, see https://regex101.com/r/w2jFRq/1

Comment: You're right :) I edited it a bit

Comment: Just a minor note, using a single character class `[\w.]+` to match either a word char or a dot can also match an address starting with a dot. (You don't have to escape the dot in the character class).